# Click on all 'see more' buttons and scrape all data from a LinkedIN profile using selenium and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am creating a general python script to scrape any LinkedIN profile. In the experience section, we find description of the experiences which are a lot of times hidden and can be shown by clicking on 'see more'. I want to click on all 'see more's and scrape the whole description. I have tried the following code for opening the profile, scrolling the page and clicking on buttons-:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Creating an instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe")

# Logging into LinkedIn
driver.get("https://linkedin.com/uas/login")
time.sleep(5)

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username.send_keys("your login email") # Enter Your Email Address

pword = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
pword.send_keys("your password") # Enter Your Password

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()

# Opening My Profile
# paste the URL of my profile here
profile_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/warikoo/"

driver.get(profile_url)  # this will open the link

start = time.time()

# will be used in the while loop
initialScroll = 0
finalScroll = 1000

while True:
   see_more = driver.find_elements_by_class('inline-show-more-text__button link') 
   
   driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo({initialScroll}, {finalScroll})")
   # this command scrolls the window starting from    
   # the pixel value stored in the initialScroll
   # variable to the pixel value stored at the
   # finalScroll variable
   initialScroll = finalScroll
   finalScroll += 1000
   
   if see_more:
       see_more.click()
   
   # we will stop the script for 3 seconds so that
   # the data can load
   time.sleep(3)

   end = time.time()
   
   # We will scroll for 20 seconds.
   if round(end - start) > 20:
        break
```

No 'see more' buttons are clicked with the above code. I have also tried to find elements by Xpath for the 'see more' but it gives following error-:
**NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:**

For scraping the experience section, I have written the following code-:

```
job_src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(job_src, 'lxml')

# Getting the HTML of the Experience section in the profile
experience = soup.find("section", {"id": "experience-section"}).find('ul')
jobs = experience.find_all('li', {'class': 'pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view'})

job_details={}
count = 0

#Looping through every experience to get its detail
for job in jobs :
    title = job.find('h3', {'class': 't-16 t-black t-bold'}).get_text()
    company = job.find('p', {'class': 'pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal'}).get_text()
    time = job.find("h4", {'class':'pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal'}).find('span', {'class': None}).get_text()
    duration = job.find("h4", {'class':'t-14 t-black--light t-normal'}).find('span', {'class': 'pv-entity__bullet-item-v2'}).get_text()
    location = job.find("h4", {'class':'pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block'}).find('span', {'class': None}).get_text()
    desc_temp = job.find("div", {'class':'inline-show-more-text inline-show-more-text--is-collapsed pv-entity__description t-14 t-black t-normal'})
    description = 'NA' if type(desc_temp) is None else desc_temp.get_text()

    #Storing all each experience detail in a dictionary
    job_dict = {
            'company': company,
            'title': title, 
            'time': time,
            'duration': duration,
            'location': location,
            'description': description
           }

    count = count + 1

    #Updating the dictionary with every loop iteration
    job_details.update({'job'+str(count): job_dict})
```

Comment: why are you using `BeautifulSoup` with `selenium`? You can parse the elements with `selenium` easily.  Check the `xpath` or the `selector` you are using for getting `see more` in Dev Tools.

Comment: @AbhishekRai I did it as I was comfortable with BS. I am looking into selenium too to parse the data. Anyways, the issue is not with parsing here. I again tried to click on 'see more' using class, xpath and selector but no progress.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why direct click on **see more** is not working but following would work in this case.

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='feed-shared-inline-show-more-text__see-more-less-toggle see-more t-14 t-black--light t-normal hoverable-link-text']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```